# Autocomplete Results Display Running Together

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a text area form field which I have set up to auto complete using jquery. The results are populating correctly, however, they are displaying as a list that just runs together horizontally. I have tried to strip out any other styling but cannot figure out the style to control this. Or maybe it is an issue in my results array. Help!

[image: run-together results]

Jquery:

```
  jQuery ->
       $('#event_course_name').autocomplete
        source: $('#event_course_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

CSS:

```
        ul.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  cursor: default;
  li {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-top: solid 1px #DDD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    a {
      color: #000;
      display: block;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    a.ui-state-hover, a.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #FFFCB2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put `$('#event_course_name').data('autocomplete-source')` into developers console in your browser, please, and paste the result here. You can see from it, if your array is okay.

Comment: it just returns /couses which I have a controller file for. 
The array returned appear like this:

https://i.imgur.com/TiDgEPI.png

Comment: well, i cannot see any error there... looks good.